# Avoid creating dual mappings from logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I notice that logstash creates an extra "keyword" field in the index mapping for every string field that it extracts from the log files and sends to elastic search.

There are many fields that I've removed completely with the [prune plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-prune.html), but there are other fields that I don't want to remove completely, but I also don't need to have a *.keyword for them.

Is there a way to have logstash only create *.keyword fields for some fields and not others? Specifically, is there a way for logstash to have a whitelist of fields that it is OK to create *.keywords for, and not do it for anything else?

*(using elasticsearch 6.x)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I'm working with for now is a [dynamic templates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html).
I can map some fields to just text and others to text and a keyword. For example:

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "doc": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                                {
                    "match_my_custom_fields": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "match": "custom_prefix_*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "text",
                            "fields": {
                                "raw": {
                                    "type": "keyword",
                                    "ignore_above": 256
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "strings_as_keywords": {
                        "match_mapping_type": "string",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "keyword",
                            "ignore_above": 256
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "properties": {
              "geoip": {
                "dynamic": true,
                "properties": {
                    "ip": {
                        "type": "ip"
                    },
                    "location": {
                        "type": "geo_point"
                    },
                    "latitude": {
                        "type": "half_float"
                    },
                    "longitude": {
                        "type": "half_float"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way, everything beginning with `custom_prefix_` will have a text and keyword field, and everything else will just have a keyword.

Of course, I somehow broke the `geoip.geo_point` that was being emitted from the `geoip` logstash plugin, and now my map visualizations won't work, so I need to figure out how to restore that.

---

*EDIT:* Got geo_point working again, see the "geoip" prop

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the mapping of the desired fields. The mapping page shows the default text type mapping:

> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.5/breaking_50_mapping_changes.html

I tried to set a field without a keyword field and it worked except you couldn't agregate on that field (I tried terms aggregation) even if you set index: true in the mapping. I might have missed something but I think this is where you should start.